# How does one use "Mail" or other keyboard keys for copying or pasting in Gnome?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, ubuntu-10.10

I'm trying to assign some of those extra keys that come with the keyboard to something useful. I know how to change their default behavior, and how to assign them to a shell script via the System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcut menu, but am not sure how what to enter in the 'command' part of a custom keyboard shortcut in order to get the normal "copy" behavior you get when using Ctrl+C.

Anyone know what I should enter in that 'command' text box to get the normal 'copy' behavior in gnome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using something like [KeyTouch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyTouch)? It looks like you want combine it with [xmacro](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/). I don't have it installed on a handy system, but I think you want a script something like

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep .07
echo KeyStrPress Control_R KeyStrPress c KeyStrRelease c KeyStrRelease Control_R | xmacroplay "$DISPLAY"
```

and call that script in your 'command' text box.